# Can't find resource dictionary WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, styles

I have my ResourceDictionary.xaml file in my Project. It's binded in App.xaml. Everything works fine, until I add this Microsoft's Combobox template: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752094.aspx

It can't find my ResourceDictionary file and throws Exception:

```
Unable to find the specified file. at Microsoft.Windows.Design.Platform.ViewProducerBase.Microsoft.Expression.DesignModel.DocumentModel.IDocumentRootResolver.GetDocumentRoot(String path)
   at Microsoft.Expression.Platform.WPF.InstanceBuilders.ResourceDictionaryInstanceBuilder.ProvideResourceDictionary(IInstanceBuilderContext context, DocumentCompositeNode resourceDictionaryReferenceNode, IDocumentRoot& relatedRoot)
```

Here is App.xaml

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
         <Setter.Value>
             <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="2">
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost"/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}" TargetName="Bd"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF1388B7" TargetName="Bd"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray" TargetName="Bd"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
         </Setter.Value>

    </Setter>

</Style>



<Style x:Key="ButtonFocusVisual">
    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Border>
                    <Rectangle Margin="2"
                 StrokeThickness="1"
                 Stroke="#60000000"
                 StrokeDashArray="1 2" />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<!-- Button -->
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels"
      Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle"
      Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle"
      Value="{StaticResource ButtonFocusVisual}" />
    <Setter Property="MinHeight"
      Value="23" />
    <Setter Property="MinWidth"
      Value="75" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Border TextBlock.Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
            x:Name="Border"
            CornerRadius="2"
            BorderThickness="1">
                    <Border.BorderBrush>
                        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0"
                             EndPoint="0,1">
                            <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                <GradientStopCollection>
                                    <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource BorderLightColor}"
                            Offset="0.0" />
                                    <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource BorderDarkColor}"
                            Offset="1.0" />
                                </GradientStopCollection>
                            </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                        </LinearGradientBrush>

                    </Border.BorderBrush>
                    <Border.Background>
                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1"
                             StartPoint="0.5,0">
                            <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}"
                        Offset="0" />
                            <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlMediumColor}"
                        Offset="1" />
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Border.Background>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.5" />
                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0"
                              To="Pressed" />
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).
                  (GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                     Value="{StaticResource ControlMouseOverColor}" />
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).
                  (GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                     Value="{StaticResource ControlPressedColor}" />
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).
                  (GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                     Value="{StaticResource PressedBorderDarkColor}" />
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).
                  (GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                     Value="{StaticResource PressedBorderLightColor}" />
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).
                  (GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                     Value="{StaticResource DisabledControlDarkColor}" />
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                  Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                     Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundColor}" />
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).
                  (GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                     Value="{StaticResource DisabledBorderDarkColor}" />
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <ContentPresenter Margin="2"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsDefault"
               Value="true">

                        <Setter TargetName="Border"
                Property="BorderBrush">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0"
                                 EndPoint="0,1">
                                    <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                        <GradientStopCollection>
                                            <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource DefaultBorderBrushLightBrush}"
                                Offset="0.0" />
                                            <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource DefaultBorderBrushDarkColor}"
                                Offset="1.0" />
                                        </GradientStopCollection>
                                    </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>

                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Color x:Key="WindowColor">#FFE8EDF9</Color>
<Color x:Key="ContentAreaColorLight">#FFC5CBF9</Color>
<Color x:Key="ContentAreaColorDark">#FF7381F9</Color>

<Color x:Key="DisabledControlLightColor">#FFE8EDF9</Color>
<Color x:Key="DisabledControlDarkColor">#FFC5CBF9</Color>
<Color x:Key="DisabledForegroundColor">#FF888888</Color>

<Color x:Key="SelectedBackgroundColor">#FFC5CBF9</Color>
<Color x:Key="SelectedUnfocusedColor">#FFDDDDDD</Color>

<Color x:Key="ControlLightColor">White</Color>
<Color x:Key="ControlMediumColor">#FF7381F9</Color>
<Color x:Key="ControlDarkColor">#FF211AA9</Color>

<Color x:Key="ControlMouseOverColor">#FF3843C4</Color>
<Color x:Key="ControlPressedColor">#FF211AA9</Color>


<Color x:Key="GlyphColor">#FF444444</Color>
<Color x:Key="GlyphMouseOver">sc#1, 0.004391443, 0.002428215, 0.242281124</Color>

<!--Border colors-->
<Color x:Key="BorderLightColor">#FFCCCCCC</Color>
<Color x:Key="BorderMediumColor">#FF888888</Color>
<Color x:Key="BorderDarkColor">#FF444444</Color>

<Color x:Key="PressedBorderLightColor">#FF888888</Color>
<Color x:Key="PressedBorderDarkColor">#FF444444</Color>

<Color x:Key="DisabledBorderLightColor">#FFAAAAAA</Color>
<Color x:Key="DisabledBorderDarkColor">#FF888888</Color>

<Color x:Key="DefaultBorderBrushDarkColor">Black</Color>

<!--Control-specific resources.-->
<Color x:Key="HeaderTopColor">#FFC5CBF9</Color>
<Color x:Key="DatagridCurrentCellBorderColor">Black</Color>
<Color x:Key="SliderTrackDarkColor">#FFC5CBF9</Color>

<Color x:Key="NavButtonFrameColor">#FF3843C4</Color>

<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="MenuPopupBrush"
                 EndPoint="0.5,1"
                 StartPoint="0.5,0">
    <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}"
            Offset="0" />
    <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlMediumColor}"
            Offset="0.5" />
    <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}"
            Offset="1" />
</LinearGradientBrush>

<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ProgressBarIndicatorAnimatedFill"
                 StartPoint="0,0"
                 EndPoint="1,0">
    <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
        <GradientStopCollection>
            <GradientStop Color="#000000FF"
                Offset="0" />
            <GradientStop Color="#600000FF"
                Offset="0.4" />
            <GradientStop Color="#600000FF"
                Offset="0.6" />
            <GradientStop Color="#000000FF"
                Offset="1" />
        </GradientStopCollection>
    </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
</LinearGradientBrush>
```

Comment: You should show your App.XAML + ResourceDictionary.xaml if you want us to troubleshoot - otherwise we're just guessing.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you've added the template properly? A missing end tag or something may be causing problems. Try commenting out large chunks of the template until you can find the minimum that will work.

Comment: I've copied all content that was there

Comment: So start commenting out stuff until your app works again. This should give you a clue to the problem.